# How to make a JButton repeat its action when clicked again?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to make the "Generate" JButton place a new word in the text area when pressed each time. I have tried loops and this has caused my GUI to stop responding.

Sample user input: clicks "Generate" button 3 times
Sample output in text area: applepotatocucumber

Any suggestions?

Here is the code:

```
 public Generator(){
    String[] words = {apple, pear, cucumber, lettuce, tomato, potato};
    String random = (words[new Random().nextInt(words.length)]);

            setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            SpringLayout sl_contentPane = new SpringLayout();
            contentPane.setLayout(sl_contentPane);

            JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Random Word Generator");
            sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblNewLabel, 10,     SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
            sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblNewLabel, 27, SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
            lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 21));
            lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);


            JLabel lblInfo = new JLabel("Result will be printed in the white space.");
            sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, lblResultsWillBe, 73, SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
            sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, lblResultsWillBe, 124, SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
            lblResultsWillBe.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            contentPane.add(lblInfo);

            JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, textArea, 150, SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
            sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, textArea, 141, SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
            sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, textArea, 12, SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
            sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, textArea, -124, SpringLayout.EAST, contentPane);
            contentPane.add(textArea);

            JButton btnGenerate = new JButton("Generate");
            sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, btnGenerate, 41, SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
            sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, btnGenerate, 163, SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
            contentPane.add(btnGenerate);
            btnGenerate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.setText(random);
                Object source = e.getSource();
                if (source == btnGenerate){
                        textArea.setText(random);
                }

            }});
            JLabel txtResults = new JLabel();
            sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, txtResults, -100, 

    SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
                sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, txtResults, -143, SpringLayout.EAST, contentPane);
            contentPane.add(txtResults);

        }
```

Comment: `textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+random);` Also get rid of `Object source = e.getSource()`;  and that if statement you won't need it in this case.

Comment: And then: read about the AWT event dispatcher thread; if you are doing the wrong things (and most things one can do are wrong in that perspective) within your actionPerformed() or other methods that are called back on events ... you freeze your UI.

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sample output in text area: applepotatocucumber

Don't use the `setText()` method. That replaces the existing text.

Instead use:

```
textArea.append(random);
```

So every time you click the button new text will be appended to the text area.

Comment: I tried this, however the "generate" button repeats the same random value and adds it on to the previous values each time it is clicked. For instance, the user clicks the button five times and the output is "appleappleappleappleapple". I want the button to place a new random string taken from the array into the text area each time the button is pressed.

Comment: @JavaWeenis, well you need to determine a new random string every time you click the button. So the randomizing code needs to be placed in the ActionListener.